# DotPeek Decompile .dll File

Tags: c#, decompiling

### When i decompile a X.dll file i can't rebuild it and i receive the following errors

---

- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error    CS1001  Identifier expected  Library    C:\Users\ ...\Managers\RpcHubManager.cs    52  Active

---

### why the dotpeek create this strange code ,"o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7  "  ,And what it mean ??,how can i solve this problem ??, thanks in advance

```
private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object n)
            {
                foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<SessionManager, string> current in RpcHubManager.Dashboard_Connections)
                {
                    System.Collections.Generic.List<SymbolMinimizedDTO> updatedSymbolsPrices = this.trader_manager.GetUpdatedSymbolsPrices(current.Key, false);
                    if (RpcHubManager.<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7 == null)
                    {
                        RpcHubManager.<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7 = CallSite<Action<CallSite, object, string>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded, "updateSymbols", null, typeof(RpcHubManager), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
                        {
                            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null)
                        }));
                    }
                    RpcHubManager.<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7.Target(RpcHubManager.<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7, this.hubContext.Clients.Client(current.Value), Json.Encode(updatedSymbolsPrices));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Well, first of all you should pick a book about C# and you will now why that code does not compile.

Comment: I suspect this question is more to do with why this decompiler produces code that cannot be re-compiled - is this correct?

Comment: @rhughes yes, exactly and what should i do in this situation, specially in this function to rebuild this library after modify it  .

Comment: @adriano i know this isnt a correct syntax of c# and the compiler cannot build the project , but my question what is this code after decompile and how can fix it ?!!!! If you have an answer share it with us ... Thank you

Comment: I was little bit sarcastic, sorry. IL has less name limitations than higher level languages (because parser is simpler). C# compiler (but not only it!) generates *impossible* names for compiler generated code (lambdas, anonymous types, methods, enumerators and so on).  Why? Because they are sure it will not conflict with code you wrote. Easy and effective. How to fix? Rename to valid names. Code will still look weird because it's generated by compiler but it will work

Answer (score 1):

Your problem because `IL` (Common Intermediate Language) allows `<` and `>` symbols in variable names, but C# doesn't.

For example:

```
RpcHubManager.<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6.<>p__Site7
```

It cannot be compiled because of `<OnTimerElapsed>o__SiteContainer6` and `<>p__Site7` name.

Replace it with

```
RpcHubManager.OnTimerElapsedo__SiteContainer6.p__Site7
```

and everything will works